# Mongoose nested sub-document duplicate key error upon insert

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hello I'm using mongoosastic plugin (wrapper for elasticsearch.js) and mongoose.js.
In a few words I have a model called Event which has children (nested sub-documents) declared as Game (model name). Further more Game has other children (nested sub documents) declared as Result (model name). So, Result is child of Game and Game is child of Event.

All of them have a property called nodeId which is unique indexed and required.
There are no duplicate nodeIds, I have checked my data programatically so I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong with my model declaration...

```
var ObjectSchema = new Schema({
    key: {
        unique: false,
        index: false,
        type: String,
        es_indexed: true
    },
    value: {
        unique: false,
        index: false,
        type: String,
        es_indexed: true
    }
});

var ResultSchema = new Schema({
    odd: {
        type: Number,
        index: true,
        es_indexed: true,
    },
    sortOrder: {
        type: Number,
        index: true,
        es_indexed: true,
    },
    specialOddsValue: {
        type: String,
        index: true,
        es_indexed: true
    },
    gameTypeResultsNr: {
        type: Number,
        index: true,
        es_indexed: true,
    },
    startDate: {
        type: Date,
        index: true,
        es_indexed: true,
        es_type: "date"
    },
    nodeId: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        index: true,
        es_indexed: true
    },
    parentNodeId: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        index: true,
        es_indexed: true
    },
    localizedNames: {
        localizedValues: {
            type: [ObjectSchema],
            es_indexed: true,
            es_type: "nested",
            es_include_in_parent: true
        }
    },
    localizedAdditionalValues: {
        localizedValues: {
            type: [ObjectSchema],
            es_indexed: true,
            es_type: "nested",
            es_include_in_parent: true
        }
    },
    additionalValues: {
        localizedValues: {
            type: [ObjectSchema],
            es_indexed: true,
            es_type: "nested",
            es_include_in_parent: true
        }
    }
});

var GameSchema = new Schema({
    gameTypeId: {
        type: Number,
        index: true,
        es_indexed: true,
    },
    betTypeAvailability: {
        type: Number,
        index: true,
        es_indexed: true,
    },
    eventNodeTypeId: {
        type: Number,
        index: true,
        es_indexed: true,
    },
    startDate: {
        type: Date,
        index: true,
        es_indexed: true,
        es_type: "date"
    },
    nodeId: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        index: true,
        es_indexed: true
    },
    parentNodeId: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        index: true,
        es_indexed: true
    },
    localizedNames: {
        localizedValues: {
            type: [ObjectSchema],
            es_indexed: true,
            es_type: "nested",
            es_include_in_parent: true
        }
    },
    localizedAdditionalValues: {
        localizedValues: {
            type: [ObjectSchema],
            es_indexed: true,
            es_type: "nested",
            es_include_in_parent: true
        }
    },
    additionalValues: {
        localizedValues: {
            type: [ObjectSchema],
            es_indexed: true,
            es_type: "nested",
            es_include_in_parent: true
        }
    },
    children: {
        type: [ResultSchema],
        index: false,
        es_indexed: true,
        es_type: "nested",
        es_include_in_parent: true
    },
    childrenCount: {
        type: Number,
        index: false,
        es_indexed: false,
    }
});

var EventSchema = new Schema({
    _id: ObjectId,
    eventNodeTypeId: {
        type: Number,
        index: true,
        es_indexed: true
    },
    status: {
        type: Number,
        index: true,
        es_indexed: true
    },
    startDate: {
        type: Date,
        index: true,
        es_indexed: true,
        es_type: "date"
    },
    _sport: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: "Sport",
        es_schema: SportSchema,
        es_indexed: true,
    },
    _league: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: "League",
        es_schema: LeagueSchema,
        es_indexed: true
    },
    _location: {
        type: ObjectId,
        ref: "Location",
        es_schema: LocationSchema,
        es_indexed: true
    },
    sportNodeId: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        index: true,
        es_indexed: true
    },
    leagueNodeId: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        index: true,
        es_indexed: true
    },
    locationNodeId: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        index: true,
        es_indexed: true
    },
    nodeId: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        index: true,
        es_indexed: true
    },
    parentNodeId: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        index: true,
        es_indexed: true
    },
    isActive: {
        type: Boolean,
        index: true,
        es_indexed: true
    },
    localizedNames: {
        localizedValues: {
            type: [ObjectSchema],
            es_indexed: true,
            es_type: "nested",
            es_include_in_parent: true
        }
    },
    localizedAdditionalValues: {
        localizedValues: {
            type: [ObjectSchema],
            es_indexed: true,
            es_type: "nested",
            es_include_in_parent: true
        }
    },
    additionalValues: {
        localizedValues: {
            type: [ObjectSchema],
            es_indexed: true,
            es_type: "nested",
            es_include_in_parent: true
        }
    },
    participants: {
        type: Array,
        index: true,
        es_indexed: true,
        es_type: "nested",
        es_include_in_parent: true
    },
    children: {
        type: [GameSchema],
        index: false,
        es_indexed: true,
        es_type: "nested",
        es_include_in_parent: true
    }
});
```

The error I'm getting upon import is the following:

```
{ MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: opap.events index: children.nodeId_1 dup key: { : null }
    at Function.MongoError.create (D:\Development\xampp\htdocs\lab\praktorio\node-tools\importer\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\error.js:31:11)
    at toError (D:\Development\xampp\htdocs\lab\praktorio\node-tools\importer\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:139:22)
    at D:\Development\xampp\htdocs\lab\praktorio\node-tools\importer\node_modules\mongodb\lib\collection.js:669:23
    at handleCallback (D:\Development\xampp\htdocs\lab\praktorio\node-tools\importer\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:120:56)
    at resultHandler (D:\Development\xampp\htdocs\lab\praktorio\node-tools\importer\node_modules\mongodb\lib\bulk\ordered.js:421:14)
    at D:\Development\xampp\htdocs\lab\praktorio\node-tools\importer\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:461:18
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
  name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: opap.events index: children.nodeId_1 dup key: { : null }',
  driver: true,
  code: 11000,
  index: 4,
  errmsg: 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: opap.events index: children.nodeId_1 dup key: { : null }',
  getOperation: [Function],
  toJSON: [Function],
  toString: [Function] }
```

Comment: The error is telling you that the `nodeId` property within the `children` property in your `Events` schema ( therefore the `nodeId` of games ) is duplicated. Since you put a unique index on this it means that value cannot exist within any other document in the collection. That's okay if you really mean it, but you are probably just trying to get "unique" items in the "array". Therefore an "index" is not the tool for this. Unique indexes are enforced collection wide.

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly, I cannot have an indexed property with the same value twice inside a collection, even if it is inside a sub-document ? ex: nodeId can't exist twice inside a collection even if it is in a child document ?

Comment: Not a "unique" property no. As said, "unique" means "one only" for the collection. As guessed, you want "unique in array", for which there are answers here already. I've given a few.

Comment: @NeilLunn, can you please provide links to answers or examples for "unique in array" - I am struggling to find any of those. Thanks.